# apache2 not responding to requests from outside the local network

Tags: apache2, lxc

My apache2 install on 15.10 is responding fine when called from the local network segment. http works externally, https times out.

I spent a couple days checking everything the docs suggest. Apache is listening on 443, ufw allows 443, 443 is visible externally, ssllabs.com oks the handshake, and everything works fine (http and https) from my dev machine. My corporate firewall forwards 443 properly. The windows server this install is supposed to replace works fine with the same firewall rules. There are no erros in any log.

What should I check next?

Update:

Turns out listening on *:443 is not supported. Details described [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts). Unfortunately fixing that issues did not fix my setup. At least now I get an error/info message.

```
[core:trace6] [pid 0] core_filters.c(527): [client 0.0.0.0:0] core_output_filter: flushing because of FLUSH bucket
[ssl:trace3] [pid 0] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1797): [client 0.0.0.0:0] OpenSSL: Loop: unknown state
[ssl:info] [pid 0] (70014)End of file found: [client 0.0.0.0:0] AH01991: SSL input filter read failed.
```

The first external https request now gets handled, but any subsequent requests fail. Requests from the local network work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a silent failure in PHP. `mcrypt_create_iv` required the source of randomness to be set to `MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM`.

I did not have the time to figure out why there was no error message, and why the server worked fine on the local network segment. I found the issue on my test server, which runs bare metal.

I did too little testing to confirm that this is related to LXC. Don't completely trust this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

1. apache ports file: listen activated on 443
2. apache active site: pointed to 443 (that's a different virtual host
   than the :80)
3. virtual host: it must include all the alias the site will be called
   by (localhost, 127.0.0.1, yoursitename.com, ecc.)
4. apache server status: running and active
5. apache log error: no errors on starting
6. host firewall: 443 opened or no operative firewall
7. host key: CA key created and associated to the site
8. router: port 443 forwarded to the host
9. intranet: check any other operative firewall
10. any firewall: no blacklisted ip/domain for connection origin
11. internet: try a traceroute to the site and give a look to connection
    times
12. portscan you external ip for :443
13. site connection: must be done prefixed by "https://"

If troubles in checking all apache config, I suggest you to install webmin on the host, and manipulate server config through it (to simplify management work).

Comment: the server responding to requests from the same network segment precludes most of these.

Comment: What do you mean? Port not open, no response from the server, server not found, etc? If you're in the same segment, just try a nmap to the server, and check ports are open. Use webmin to configure apache virtual host and check the status. Looking at the server from the same segment just means to check if the host config is correct or not, no via to check. And that's just a matter of apache.

Comment: I understand that simple problems are most often the source of the problem, until they are not.